# Why is the *_url in mso condition breaking the button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, outlook, html-email

I have a rails project that needs to send some emails and inside the email there is a link/button. In web based email clients and on my phone it is displaying correct, but in outlook on desktop it is displaying the code instead of the button.

```
/[if mso] <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="#{crm_tasks_url}" style="height:62px;width:271px;v-text-anchor:middle;" arcsize="57%" stroke="false" fillcolor="#dc0030"><w:anchorlock/><v:textbox inset="0px,0px,0px,0px"><center style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px">
%a{:href => "#{crm_tasks_url}", :style => "text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;color:#ffffff;background-color:#dc0030;border-radius:35px;width:auto;border-top:0px solid transparent;font-weight:undefined;border-right:0px solid transparent;border-bottom:0px solid transparent;border-left:0px solid transparent;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;text-align:center;mso-border-alt:none;word-break:keep-all;", :target => "_blank"}
  %span{:style => "padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;font-size:15px;display:inline-block;letter-spacing:normal;"}
    %span{:style => "margin: 0; word-break: break-word; line-height: 30px;"}
      %strong BEKIJK TAAK
/[if mso] </center></v:textbox></v:roundrect>
```

The code above is giving me the following result in outlook:

`<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://localhost:3000/crm/taken" style="height:62px;width:271px;v-text-anchor:middle;" arcsize="57%" stroke="false" fillcolor="#dc0030"><w:anchorlock/><v:textbox inset="0px,0px,0px,0px"><center style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px"> BEKIJK TAAK`

If i change the href inside the `/[if mso]` block to: `http://localhost:3000/crm/taken` it works as expected and displays the button.

Now you would say: You already got your solution, but no. I also got a invitation email that sends an invitation_token and it is not possible to hard code that token.

I am using rails 7 and i also have a project in rails 6 that also sends emails with links/buttons and that works fine. I copied the complete email view but still got the problem. Not sure if that has anything to do with the rails versions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Rails bug, but there is an alternative way that takes the href out of the VML that would be worth trying:

```
<!--[if mso]>
            <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" style="height:62px;width:271px;v-text-anchor:middle;" arcsize="57%" stroke="false" fillcolor="#dc0030" alt="" role="presentation">
            <w:anchorlock/>
            <center>
            <![endif]-->
            <a href="https://www.google.com" style="background-color:#dc0030;border-radius:25px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-size:16px; line-height: 50px;font-weight: bold;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" class="buttonlink">
                Button Text
            </a>
            <!--[if mso]>
            </center>
            </v:roundrect>
        <![endif]-->
```

There's less risk in this one too as you don't have to try and remember to update the URL in two places.

Comment: It is less risk yes and the button is showing up in outlook. But in other mail clients the button is not showing up....

Comment: ok then there's something going on either with another part of your code or the rails environment.

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but for now I use a text link instead of a button and that is working fine.